# How to retrieve the aggregated value in a panda grouped data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I have a data frame `my_df`:

```
id       color 
--------------------     
001       red
001       blue
001       yellow
002       green
002       black
003       yellow
003       white
003       blue
```

Then I did:

```
grouped_df = my_df.groupby('id')
a = grouped_df['id'].apply(lambda x: set(x.tolist()))
```

Then a looks like this:

```
id
--------------------------------
001       {red,blue,yellow}
002       {green,black}
003       {yellow,white,blue}
```

How do I loop over `a`, so I can find the corresponding set for each id? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it something like `a['001']` or `[a[i] for i in a.index]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try applying `set` with a `groupby`

```
my_df.groupby('id').color.apply(set)

id
1      {blue, red, yellow}
2           {black, green}
3    {white, yellow, blue}
Name: color, dtype: object
```

***explanation***
The key difference between what you did and what I did was that I refined the grouping with `.color` then applied `set`.  This ensures that I'm applying `set` on a series and not a dataframe.

---

if you assign the results of the `groupby` to a variable... say `g`

```
g = my_df.groupby('id').color.apply(set)
```

Then each group can be easily referenced by the index value

```
g.loc[1]

{'blue', 'red', 'yellow'}
```

you can loop like this

```
for i, v in g.iteritems():
    print(i, v)

1 {'blue', 'red', 'yellow'}
2 {'black', 'green'}
3 {'white', 'yellow', 'blue'}
```

Comment: Thanks. So how do I loop over all records to find when id = 1, the set value is {blue, red, yellow}, when id =2, the set value is {black, green} ... etc. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The iteration works great. Just a minor part: but the .apply(set) is not really returning a set ... I mean in some cases, it has duplicated items like { 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow'}. Is it possible to remove the duplicates in the set? Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame it should absolutely be returning a `set`.  If it isn't then my first hunch is that `'blue'` and `'blue'` are different somehow.

Comment: @Edamame if you can provide data that reproduces that, I'd like to see.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for my mistakes and thank you!